# Remotely activate script via URL

Tags: javascript, url, post, get, send

How can i create a URL that activates a script on my website.

something like: www.website.com/emergency/command123 or some code that activates the script.

I am building an emergency system. I am working with software that requieres a URL to activate a send command to the programm that activates triggers on a screen, showing exit signs etc.

I have searched the net but not found anything, or i am looking in the wrong direction. Or if there is a forum on this, please redirect me.

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you want to do ? Call an url that will exec a bash ?

Comment: Create a CURL call from the backend, if you want to do a cross domain url call.. Use ajax if u are using same domain. Which language u r using in d backend?

Comment: Javascript code runs in the browser, on the client side - unless you are using server (code) side scripting. You should be able to easily achieve this by means of a php script. You can call the php script with appropriate authentication and then the script could literally do anything, including running an executable on the server.

Comment: In php you can use exec, shell_exec, system or passthru functions to execute commands.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Is there any tutorial about this availeble so i only ajust the url's or coding?